# Change the Parent of a Commit in Git

Tags: git, git-branch

I am extracting some folders as submodules and after running a:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <my-path> myBranch
```

I am getting 2 branches that have no parent in common:

[image: no common ancestor]

This image is from GitKraken and `develop` appears totally detached from `master`.

GitKraken don't even allow me to rebase `develop` on `master`, last time this happened I had to send a `rebase` using the terminal and had to deal with conflicts on EVERY SINGLE document shared by both branches (some 15 documents), so I rather avoid this kind of approach this time.

I am not a git specialist but I think `git filter-branch` option `--parent-filter <command>` does what I want. It should set `master` as the parent of `develop`, but I can't find any examples on how to use this command and I have no idea on how to format it.

### **So I would like to know how to set `master` as the parent of `develop` by rewriting history.**

Comment: You could search for .git/info/grafts

Comment: I have, I don't like them since they need special cloning techniques, I want it to be transparent to the repository

Comment: I doubt somewhat that this *does* do what you want—not that I am at all sure what you really want in the end—but @LaurentG's answer gets you most of the way there: use a graft, or `git replace`, to join the histories up any way you like. Then use `git filter-branch -- --all` to make the graft-or-replacement permanent. This will re-use all the untouched commits (so it's pretty slow) and copy the `develop` commits to new commits that form the new history. (It seems likely to me that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) here.)

Comment: I tried to avoid an X Y problem here by making the final question bold, this way I tried to say "hey this is my actual problem, everything before this was just how I think it might be solved"

Comment: @mFeinstein You have specified you want to rewrite history.  However, without knowing what you want history to look like, I don't think this question can be answered.

Comment: Master as the parent of develop, as I have stated before